# How to use info.plist in Xcode UITest target?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, info.plist

I have a project with iOS app and UITests targets.
UITest target has its own info.plist, and I tried to add additional row:
[image: info.plist in UITest target]

But during tests executing new row is unavailable in code:

```
(lldb) po Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["EMAIL"]
nil
(lldb) po Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "EMAIL")
nil
```

In Xcode since version 13 info.plist doesn't create as separate file. But after adding new row I found a new one in the project tree, and it contain my row only without other rows that were added as default.
In build settings I removed generating of info.plist. After that file contains all rows.
But in both cases my row is unavailable.
Are info.plist settings even available in UITest targets? Or I should take them some other way? Maybe UITest should call some other bundle, not main like 'Bundle.main'?

**Upd:**
I found that one of bundles already contains necessary value:

```swift
if let bundle = Bundle.allBundles.first(where: { $0.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "EMAIL") is String }),
   let email = bundle.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "EMAIL") as? String {
    print(email) // it works
}
```

So, in Xcode UITests we should use some other bundle, not main. But what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to get your UITest's target bundle?

For example:

```swift
func getEmail() -> String?  {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let email = bundle.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "EMAIL") as? String {
        return email
    }
    return nil
}
```